# Vagrant/Mac port forwarding is not working

Tags: apache, vagrant, portforwarding, vagrantfile

Mac OS here. I am unable to get Vagrant port-forwarding to work from my guest VMs to my host. I am following the [Networking/Port-Forwarding tutorial](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/networking.html) verbatim.

Here's my project:

```
testvm/
    Vagrantfile
    bootstrap.sh
```

Where `bootstrap.sh` installs Apache httpd:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update
apt-get install -y apache2
if ! [ -L /var/www ]; then
    rm -rf /var/www
    ln -fs /vagrant /var/www
fi
```

And my `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4567
    config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
end
```

When I `vagrant up` I get no errors, but when I open a web browser and go to `http://127.0.0.1:4567` and I get a Safari "*Failed to open page*", instead of the "*Hey it works!*"-type page you typically get with httpd.

Any ideas as to what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the firewall on the VM is disabled/allows access to port 80?

Inside of the VM does it work as expected with

```
$ curl http://localhost
```

Comment: Not sure why i got downvoted. I asked this because nowhere do i see anything starting or checking apache service status after installing it.